# How to remove duplicated fields in NSMutableArray which includes NSDictionary in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I have NSMutableArray which includes NSDictionary.
And I want to remove duplicated dictionaries in array.
As you can see from array there are some dictionaries which _id is same.
I want to delete all of duplicated dictionaries.

Like

```
{
  "1": {
    "_id": 1
   "-name": "test1"
  }
  "2": {
    "_id": 2
   "-name": "test2"
  }
  "3": {
    "_id": 1
   "-name": "test1"
  }
  "4": {
    "_id": 3
   "-name": "test3"
  }
  "5": {
    "_id": 2
   "-name": "test2"
  }
}
```

Here's my code.

```
let filteredArray:NSMutableArray = []
for matchData in self.arrayUserMatches {
    let matchDictionary = matchData as? NSDictionary
    if let matchID = matchDictionary?.value(forKey: "_id") {
        let hasDuplicate = filteredArray.filtered(using: NSPredicate(format: "_id == %@", (matchID as! String))).count > 0
        if !hasDuplicate {
            filteredArray.add(matchDictionary)
        }
    }
}
```

But it occurs error like `reason: '[<_SwiftValue 0x6180002419b0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _id.`

Is there anybody who has experience in this area?

Comment: As always, don't use mutable Foundation collection types in Swift and don't use `valueForKey` unless you know what KVC is and you really need it.

Comment: but this is big project and can't change now, can you please provide me solution for this?

Comment: You tell us that you have NSMutableArray, but it's not in fact an array, but a dictionary with nested dictionaries

Comment: There is no array in the JSON. Apart from that instead of permanently filtering the array use a `Set` and add the `id` values. Then you have only to check if a value is in the set.

Comment: @DavidJonker Try to use `self.arrayUserMatches.allValues` to iterate throug values in the dictionary you posted

Answer (score 1):

Though you should use Swift collections whenever possible, I will porvide an example with NSDictionary. 
Let's assume you have an NSDictionary with non-unique dictionaries inside. I will create it from swift dictionary and later will operate with Foundation objects only.

```
let input = [
    "1":[
        "_id": 1,
        "-name": "test1"
    ],
    "2": [
        "_id": 2,
        "-name": "test2"
    ],
    "3": [
        "_id": 1,
        "-name": "test1"
    ],
    "4": [
        "_id": 3,
        "-name": "test3"
    ],
    "5": [
        "_id": 2,
        "-name": "test2"
    ]

]
let inputDict = NSDictionary(dictionary: input)
```

I assume you consider a dictionary is a duplicate if it has the same `_id`:

```
let uniqueDict = NSMutableDictionary()
for value in inputDict.allValues {
    if let dictionary = value as? NSDictionary {
        let key = dictionary["_id"] as! Int
        uniqueDict[key] = dictionary
    }
}
print("unique values: \(uniqueDict.allValues)")
```

Output:

```
unique values: [{
    "-name" = test3;
    "_id" = 3;
}, {
    "-name" = test1;
    "_id" = 1;
}, {
    "-name" = test2;
    "_id" = 2;
}]
```